# AES Encryption with pointers

Tags: c#, .net, security, pointers, encryption

I'm using the

```
Aes
```

class to encrypt some bytes. I can call

```
CreateEncryptor
```

method to get a `ICryptoTransform`, and then appropriately use it from there. However, the data I'm encrypting is a pointer to some memory. (a `byte*`). ICryptoTransform only accepts `byte[]`'s

My question is **do I have to COPY the pointer into a managed array before using it for AES?**

Comment: How did you create the memory for the array? is the array a consistent size?

Comment: @MichaelRandall For memory for the array, I assume you mean the pointer (ie the source of data). That pointer comes from unmanaged memory. Yes, the pointer is a consistent size, until the final block.

Comment: Where does the `byte *` come from. C# programs generally don't deal with pointers

Comment: @Flydog57 byte* comes from an unmanaged library.

Comment: Do you call that unmanaged library? If so, what does your code look like. Typically code relies on the P/Invoke marshaller to do this conversion

Comment: There is no much you can do here if you are trying to save every last allocation. There is no point using span as you would have to call ToArray, the only real option you have i see, is to use a static buffer which would save continued allocations but wouldn't be thread safe. Event then you would need cast it, which there is a few hacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to copy. Unmanaged pointer `byte *` coming from unmanaged library will not have the extra information the managed `byte[]` has which are the length, type handle so that CLR knows what type this memory refers to and sync block index used by the lock keyword.

So any managed method expecting `byte[]` is expecting the array passed to conform to the .NET object format.
For example if the `ICryptoTransform` methods attempt to access the length of the array, it will not find it in the unmanaged `byte *` pointer. If it attempts to obtain a lock on the `byte[]` array using `lock` keyword, it expects a Sync block index, etc.

The opposite works though, you can use the `fixed` keyword to obtain a pointer to the first element in the `byte[]` array. This is because code expecting `byte*` doesn't care about the extra information in `byte[]` (though a lot unmanaged code may care about length and  require you to pass length as a separate argument).

Comment: Oh well. I expected so. I hope it will still be fast.